# Why can't I directly add attributes to any python object?

Tags: python, attributes, object

I have this code:

```
>>> class G:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = 20
...
>>> gg = G()
>>> gg.x
20
>>> gg.y = 2000
```

And this code:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> my_obj = datetime.now()
>>> my_obj.interesting = 1
*** AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'interesting'
```

From my Python knowledge, I would say that `datetime` overrides `setattr`/`getattr`, but I am not sure. Could you shed some light here?

EDIT: I'm not specifically interested in `datetime`. I was wondering about objects in general.

Comment: "I was wondering about objects in general."  What?  You show a general example of a general class which generally has attributes added.  What does your edit mean?

Comment: It means that I was curious about all the classes, not just datetime. I posted this question because I saw that to some classes I could add attributes, while to others I couldn't.

Comment: @Geo: some classes are different -- there's no "general" rule.  As your question notes -- some classes can and some classes can't.  Since your question shows that there's no general rule, what are you asking?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My guess, is that the implementation of datetime uses [__slots__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#id3) for better performance.

When using `__slots__`, the interpreter reserves storage for just the attributes listed, nothing else. This gives better performance and uses less storage, but it also means you can't add new attributes at will.

Read more here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Datetime is actually written in C, which gives behaviour very similar to writing a python object that uses __slots__. Slots are a way of writing objects in python that are almost as efficient as the C versions, without resorting to c

Comment: So you could see the behaviour because the object is written in c, because it uses setattr, or because of slots :-)

Answer (score 18):

It's written in C

http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/datetimemodule.c?view=markup

It doesn't seem to implement setattr.

Answer (score 3):

While the question has already been answered; if anyone is interested in a workaround, here's an example --

```
mydate = datetime.date(2013, 3, 26)
mydate.special = 'Some special date annotation'  # doesn't work
...
class CustomDate(datetime.date):
    pass
mydate = datetime.date(2013, 3, 26)
mydate = CustomDate(mydate.year, mydate.month, mydate.day)
mydate.special = 'Some special date annotation'  # works
```

Comment: Is this legit? (I mean, does it not have drawbacks?)