# what makes user defined objects not throw AttributeError in Python?

Tags: python, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I directly add attributes to any python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623520/why-cant-i-directly-add-attributes-to-any-python-object)
>   [Why can't you add attributes to object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285269/why-cant-you-add-attributes-to-object-in-python)

The following code does not throw AttributeError

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'A'
        self.b = 'B'
my_obj = MyClass()
my_obj.c = 'C'
```

That contrasts with

```
>>> {}.a = 'A'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'a'
```

What makes such difference? Is it about dict being a built-in class while MyClass being user defined?

Comment: The real question is more *what makes some objects throw AttributeErrors when setting* - Python is dynamic, so it's natural you should be able to do this, not the other way around.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285269/why-cant-you-add-attributes-to-object-in-python   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072649/python-language-question-attributes-of-object-vs-function

Comment: The first link given by mgilson above has a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that instances of user-defined classes have a dictionary of attributes associated with them by default.  You can access this dictionary using `vars(my_obj)` or `my_obj.__dict__`.  You can prevent the creation of an attribute dictionary by defining `__slots__`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __slots__ = []
```

Built-in types could also provide an attribute dictionary, but usually they don't.  An example of a built-in type that *does* support attributes is the type of a function.